# Display Carousels In one Row on Small Devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here is a sample bootstrap carousel from [codepen](https://codepen.io/ygoex/full/meeaGw/) and here's one from [bootsnip](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-carousel). Most of them follow the typical HTMl structure like this.

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="img1.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="img2.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
```

These work fine on Desktops as they produce carousels like this:
[image]

But switch to Mobile devices and the carousel splits into multiple rows as shown here:
[image]

This is not my desired behavior as the very purpose of using a carousel is lost if images take up space in multiple rows.

On mobile devices I want only one product to show at a time (in a single row) and the subsequent products show on clicking the left or right carousel controls.

How do I do that ?

Comment: Hi @tao, can you try this `.carousel-inner > .item > img
        {
            margin:auto;
        }`

Comment: that didn't work buddy :(

Comment: Ah I see sry it didn't help you.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? My assumption is.... is this correct?  Assume 8 products ... [A] on desktop show 1 2 3 4 and on right click show 2 3 4 5 ... and on mobile show 1 and on right scroll show 2.  Or is it [B] on desktop show 1 2 3 4 and on right show 5 6 7 8, and on mobile show 1 2 3 4 and then 5 6 7 8 ?

Comment: @Vino - I am OK with any of the two options you have mentioned, just with the constraint that the carousel should show in one row and with one product at a time on mobile devices

Comment: Okay - see answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with others, its better to use some other plugin for this functionality. I suggest [owlcarousel2](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/). If you want a bootstrap only solution here is an implementation.

HTML

```
<div class="carousel slide multi-carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x400/000/fff?text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x400/000/fff?text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x400/000/fff?text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x400/000/fff?text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x400/000/fff?text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x400/000/fff?text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x400/000/fff?text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x400/000/fff?text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -100%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  100% ; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left: -100% ; }
.active > div { display:none; }
.active > div:nth-child(1) { display:block; }

@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {  
      .carousel-inner > .item.next,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
      }
      .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
      }    
  }   

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -50% ; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  50% ; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -50% ; }
    .active > div { display:none; }
    .active > div:nth-child(1) { display:block; }
  .active > div:nth-child(2) { display:block; }

  @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {  
      .carousel-inner > .item.next,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
      }
      .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
      }    
  }   
} 

@media (min-width: 992px ) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -33% ; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  33% ; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -33% ; }   
  .active > div:nth-child(1) { display:block; }
  .active > div:nth-child(2) { display:block; }
  .active > div:nth-child(3) { display:block; }

  @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {  
      .carousel-inner > .item.next,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(33.33%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(33.33%, 0, 0);
      }
      .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33.33%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(-33.33%, 0, 0);
      }    
  }      
}

@media (min-width: 1200px ) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25% ; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  25% ; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -25% ; }   
  .active > div:nth-child(1) { display:block; }
  .active > div:nth-child(2) { display:block; }
  .active > div:nth-child(3) { display:block; }
   .active > div:nth-child(4) { display:block; }

  @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {  
      .carousel-inner > .item.next,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
      }
      .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
      .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
      }    
  }      
}
```

JS

```
$('.multi-carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

[codepen link](http://codepen.io/tmg/pen/YWWbyW?editors=1100).

Comment: your bootstrap solution seems to work well. Any reason why you still suggesting use of plugins ?

Comment: It works, but its made for 4 images at lg, 3 at md, 2 at sm and 1 at xs. If you need to change this, you need to make changes to css and js maybe. Its just easier with another plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an existing carrousel library like [Lightslider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html). I think that it will fit your requirements.

Look at the first example, it gives support for responsiveness

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#responsive').lightSlider({
        item:4,
        loop:false,
        slideMove:2,
        easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)',
        speed:600,
        responsive : [
            {
                breakpoint:800,
                settings: {
                    item:3,
                    slideMove:1,
                    slideMargin:6,
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint:480,
                settings: {
                    item:2,
                    slideMove:1
                  }
            }
        ]
    });  
});
```

Another alternative would be [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). I have used it in some of my projects and it works like a charm.

Comment: thanks..exactly the behavior I wanted. Will accept your answer, If I don't get a bootstrap specific answer within next 2 days.

Comment: @tao I have a added a possible solution using only CSS but I haven't tested it at all but seems that is limiting the height when you are in a mobile

Comment: that was a nice try, but didn't work as expected. The issue is suppose there are 8 products, 4 show up at a time, then using the max-height property, the slider keeps rotating between the 1st image and the 5th image, all other images do not show up at all on smaller devices.

Comment: Yeah you are right, answer edited! I have added a link to another carrousel library that works like a charm, you should give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

bx-slider is another option - that allows single images on small viewports

Answer (score 1):

The Carousel in Bootstrap is in itself not responsive...

If you need a responsive slider then you need to add on ... something like Slick (mentioned by @miquelarranz) will do.

If you need to lay out 4 items then treat the inner content of each `.item` `<div>` like a mini window... thus in it you need to create a responsive layout.

Also... mobiles will size to `xs` so you want to use `.col-xs-*`

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinorodrigues/6ntgu3rp/) for a working example.

Comment: Add `.img-responsive` to make the images scale down... [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinorodrigues/6ntgu3rp/1/)